# Addition (i.e. +) extension method with a generic C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I'm trying to write a generic Dictionary extension method like so. TValue will always be an int but TKey could be a string or a DateTime.

```
public static void AddOrIncrement<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue value) 
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dict.Add(key, value);
    }
    else
    {
        dict[key] += value;
    }
}
```

But this won't compile - Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TValue' and 'TValue'.

So then I try:

```
public static void AddOrIncrement<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue value) where TValue : int
```

but that doesn't compile either.
So then I tried:

```
public static void AddOrIncrement<TKey, int>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key, int value)
```

which doesn't compile - "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public static void AddOrIncrement<TKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key, int value)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to make an extension method that takes only one generic parameter:

```
public static void AddOrIncrement<TKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key, int value)
```